# How Domain Modeling In Grails Affected By The Field Attributes?

Tags: grails, groovy, dns

Lets say I have a domain class named `Tag` in my Grails application.

```
class Tag {
    String name // line number 1
    User user  // Line number 2
        static constraints = {
        }
    static belongsTo = [User, Post]
}
```

I'm creating a relationship between `User` and `Tag` with the help of `belongsTo` keyword. But I have a doubt on `line number 2`, which is `User user`. Now placing this code in my `Tag` class affect the relationship between `Tag` and `User` in any way or it is only matter what we provide in `belongsTo` keyword?

And there are any tools to **visualize** the relationship between any classes in Grails application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`belongsTo` with several classes is often suspect, as it means that instances will be in a composition relationships with several other domain objects. In my experience, it's only useful if you know one will always be `null` when the other is set (but still, you may prefer to have `TagUser` and `TagPost` derive a `Tag` class instead). I would suggest you remove one of the `belongsTo` (probably Post).

In your `Post` and `User` classes you probably have a `hasMany` relationship. It's enough to create the relationship and don't *have to* add `belongsTo` in `Tag`. The only advantage of using `belongsTo` is that updating or deleting a `User` or `Post` will cascade and save `Tags` as well.

If your use case for Tag is the conventional one (like tags on stackoverflow), you are trying to create many-to-many relationships (one user has many tags and one tag has many users. Same for post). You may use belongsTo in a many-to-many relationship to indicate who *owns* the relation. Read [the documentation on many-to-many](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.1.3%20Many-to-many) to understand how such relationships work.

Regarding your last question, IntelliJ has an integrated Domain classes dependencies visualization feature.

Comment: No. If you have a one-to-many relationship, or one-to-one relationship, with strong dependency between the objects (for instance, *deleting a user should delete its tags*), then you **should** use `belongsTo`. Look at [GORM gotcha](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) to understand the meaning and implications of `belongsTo`.